# YahooMaps or OpenStreetMaps in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

Has anyone seen an example of using the YahooMaps API in silverlight (2.0)? Specifically the JSON API? Yahoo publishes tutorial for Flash but not SL. I am trying to understand how to process the JSON reply from the server, which looks something like this:

var YAHOO=window.YAHOO||{};
YAHOO.namespace=function(_1){
        if(!_1||!_1.length){
                return null;
        }
        var _2=_1.split(".");
        var _3=YAHOO;
        for(var i=(_2[0]=="YAHOO")?1:0;i<_2.length;++i){
                _3[_2[i]]=_3[_2[i]]||{};
                _3=_3[_2[i]];
        }
return _3;
};
YAHOO.namespace("util");
YAHOO.namespace("widget");
YAHOO.namespace("example");

var YMAPPID = "mykey....";
function _ywjs(inc) { var o='<'+'script src="'+inc+'"'+' type="text/javascript"><'+'/script>'; document.write(o); }_ywjs('zttp://l.yimg.com/d/lib/common/utils/2/dom_2.0.1-b2.js');
_ywjs('zttp://l.yimg.com/d/lib/common/utils/2/event_2.0.0-b2.js');
_ywjs('zttp://l.yimg.com/d/lib/common/utils/2/dragdrop_2.0.1-b4.js');
_ywjs('zttp://l.yimg.com/d/lib/common/utils/2/animation_2.0.1-b2.js');
_ywjs('zttp://l.yimg.com/d/lib/map/js/api/ymapapi_3_8_2_3.js');<!-- xm3.maps.re3.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Thu Jul 16 16:18:46 PDT 2009 -->

(replace zttp with http in the above code, this web page things I'm spamming)

Failing that, what about OpenStreetMaps?

Answer (score 0):

OpenStreetMaps works just fine in the new Silverlight Map control.

Answer (score 0):

```
BaseUri= "http://us.maps2.yimg.com/us.png.maps.yimg.com/png?v=3.52&t=m&x={0}&y={1}&z={2}";

public override Uri GetUri(int x, int y, int zoomLevel)
{
    double posY;
    double zoom;
    checked
    {
        zoom = 18 - zoomLevel;
    }
    double num4 = Math.Pow(2.0, zoomLevel)/2.0;

    if (y < num4)
        posY = (num4 - Convert.ToDouble(y)) - 1.0;
    else
        posY = ((Convert.ToDouble(y) + 1) - num4)*-1.0;
    return new Uri(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, UriFormat, x, posY, zoom));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Silverlight, a Microsoft technology, why not use the Bing / Virtual Earth mapping SDK.  I think it would be a lot easier to use if you're doing anything but the most trivial display of a map.  I haven't used it recently, but did a little toying around with it when it was still a CTP.  Seemed really easy to add custom controls and styles to the map (say you wanted to mark locations with a push pin).

Here's a recent article I found that should give you a quickstart on it.

http://www.bing.com/community/blogs/maps/archive/2009/11/09/bing-maps-silverlight-control-1-0-released.aspx